# How to hide overflow images in row class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap, I have divided my screen into two rows where 1 row has 62% and the other has remaining.

```
<style>
    .full-image
    {
      height:62%;
    }
</style>
<body
    <div class="row full-image">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src=".." style="overflow:hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     ....
    </div>
</body>
```

Now my image in row1 is getting overflow and hiding row2. Can someone help me out on this.

Comment: Snippet, Fiddle, or CodePen please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/toastEater/pen/RxQEoj

```
<style>
.full-image{
  height:62vh; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="row full-image">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YWbnI93.jpg"> 
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Anything here
</div>   
</body>
```